# I need to know what is the coefficient?

Tags: roots

I'm solving a exercise and I can't figure out something that I need to know to solve it... I need to know what is the coefficient of ∜x.
I would appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: What is the context of the problem?

Comment: The coefficient of $\sqrt[4]{x}$ is $1$.

Comment: I need to calculate the sum of coefficients for a binomial expression, in order to find the value of n. I also know that the sum equals 256.

Comment: Perhaps try stating the problem **in its entirety** in the question above...there aren't terribly many mind readers around Math.SE.

Comment: Michael Burr, thank you!

Comment: David, you're right. But I've already understood the problem.

Comment: Please post the entire problem so that others who come to the site can have a similar question answered (even if your question has been answered).  This prevents double posting of the same question.